# Nodejs: how to create a zip file with a existing file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is there a simple way of creating a zip file and add a file to it in nodejs?

I found tons of examples describing following:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
```

What I need to do is

```
1. create a zip file
2. add an existing file, not a block of text 
3. save the file
```

I used to do this in python with following code

```
with ZipFile('myzipfile.zip', 'w') as zip_write:
        zip_write.write('myfile.txt')
```

what would the node's equivalent of creating an zip file and adding an existing file to it?

Comment: you could use this node library https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip

Comment: I just checked the github description.  it looks like it will do what I need.  thanks!

Comment: I tried, but it is missing type declaration for typescript project unfortunately.

Comment: then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip it is similar and it also has @types/adm-zip

Comment: @Kay I am currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver for this functionality.

Comment: @Serhii Yukhnevych it worked good.  Could you please post your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zip your files using `node.js` you can use following library. https://npmjs.com/package/adm-zip
Also, it has typings that you can use `@types/adm-zip`